# Mac OS X PDF manipulation

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf, sdk

I'm new to mac OS developing (I've been only developing on iOS before)

I've created a mac application. That last thing I need to do is the following:

Either:

1. Open an existing pdf file at given page

or

2. create new pdf file from the existing pdf file containing pages between given page and given page and open it.

Example:

1. parameters: given page : 47 --> open pdf file at page 47

or

2. parameters: given pages : 47, 55 --> create a new pdf file containing 9 pages (pages 47 to 55 from the initial pdf) and open it (somehow).

How should I go about this?

Is it necessary to create another view and process each pdf page using pdf kit on my own mac app control? Or is there any way I could use , say.. , Adobe to open the pdf at a given page?

Any advice should do :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up using NSPanel with PDFView (Quartz framework) to open the pdf at specified page.. Maybe this will help someone